# Is there any harm in using the MariaDB client to connect to a MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I installed MariaDB on my server (both client & server), and now want to also connect to an external MySQL server from it.

It seems like although the client command is `mysql`, the version is MariaDB:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.4-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Is there any harm in using this to connect to MySQL servers?

Comment: Almost certainly not; on the one hand, the protocols are probably still identical or very nearly so, and on the other, an impedance mismatch between them should result in nothing worse than a forcible disconnect or an error message on the client side.